# get_users is expecting unserialized meta_value

Tags: user-meta, users

I'm trying to get all users assigned to a custom usermeta. I know that `get_users()` is supposed to work; however, it doesn't seem to be working. What I have is a usermeta storing a category ID and I'm trying to use `'meta_value' => $cat_id` to query the database. So this is the code I have:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'custom-usermeta',
    'meta_value' => $cat_id
);
$users = get_users( $args );
```

and here is how I'm saving it:

```
update_user_meta( $user_id,'custom-usermeta',$cat_id);
```

`$cat_id` is an array.

But this isn't working. What I've figured out so far is that the `meta_value` expects an unserialized value. How can I get that to work? I tried the `'meta_compare' => 'LIKE'` but then that just about grabs everything (because of the way Wordpress serializes the values). Is there anything else I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

In your original code, you're not passing an operator to `meta_compare`. Note that [`get_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) does *not* define a default operator. Try using `'='`:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'custom-usermeta',
    'meta_value' => $cat_id,
    'meta_compare' => '='
);
$users = get_users( $args );
```

As a diagnostic, you might make sure that the problem isn't the saving/querying by your custom user metadata. Replace the meta_key and meta_value with one of the default WP user meta keys, just to see if anything is returned. (Easiest might be the user role?)

And this one is a long-shot, but: even though the [`get_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) Codex documentation says otherwise, from what I can gather from source, the `meta_query` for [`WP_user_query`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.1/wp-includes/user.php#L335) *should* be the same as the `meta_query` for `WP_query` - in which case, have you tried putting your meta query in an *array*? e.g.:

```
$args = array(
    array( 
        'meta_key' => 'custom-usermeta',
        'meta_value' => $cat_id
    )
);
$users = get_users( $args );
```

Cf. [`WP_Query` usage of `meta_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Comment: Thanks for helping Chip! I tested to see if I was getting the same error with other user_meta as you suggested and I tried wp_capabilities since it was serialized the way my data is and it wouldn't grab that info either. Maybe wordpress can't use the `=` operator on serialized data? I also tried putting the query in an array, but that just pulled all wp_capabilities, ignoring my query as far as `meta-value`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to user a "direct" [`WP_User_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query).

```
$user_search = new WP_User_Query( array( 
    'orderby' => 'display_name',
    'fields' => 'all_with_meta',
    'meta_key' => 'CAT OR WHATEVER KEY NAME',
    'meta_value' => $cat_id,
    'meta_compare' => '='
) );
$users = $user_search->get_results();
```

Not tested, but it should work.

**Update**

As far as I can see, the `$meta_value` inside `update_metadata()` (the function that gets wrapped by `update_user_meta()`), takes a single value. The only way it can get serialized is `maybe_serialize();`, which only serializes on demand. So the problem must be on your side and the `$cat_ID` meta value.

You can recheck close before the `maybe_serialize()` with the following filter:

```
apply_filters( "update_{$meta_type}_metadata", null, $object_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value )
```

`{$meta_type}` would be `user` in this case. Just drop your `$cat_ID` inside some test function to see what's happening.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I've tried using the `=` operator and it didn't work since it's expecting a serialized response. I just tried using the "direct" WP_User_Query too, and unfortunately that didn't work either.

Comment: Hm. You should show us how you save the user data I guess.

Comment: See update.(filler)

Comment: Thanks for still helping. I'm not running through in serialization process. I'm just grabbing the `POST` data, which is an array, and then calling the `update_user_meta` function. Wordpress does the serializing own its own.

Comment: @john Have you checked using the provided filter in the update?

Comment: And if so: Link to a pastebin (or similar) with the result.

Comment: I've tried it, but could you clarify what the `object_id` is. I assumed it was the user ID, but I wasn't sure. I tried it without it and I'm not getting anything. I tried it with just the `update_user_metadata` and `$cat_id` and its just responding `Array`. So I'm guessing that the `$object_id` is the key somehow. I couldn't exactly tell what this function was doing by looking at the Wordpress Codex.